# Can you spot the mistake here?

Tags: number-theory, conjectures

assume that :
$$x^{3} + y^{3} = z^{3}$$
so :
$$z^{3} - y^{3} = x^{3}$$
$$z^{3} ≡ y^{3}\bmod x$$
$$z ≡ y\bmod x $$
$$z-y = x $$
and now let's plug this result to the original equation:
$$(z-y)^{3} + y^{3} = z^{3}$$
$$z^{3}-3z^{2}y+3zy^{2}-y^{3}+y^{3}=z^3$$
by simplfying, we get this:
$$3zy^{2} = 3z^{2}y$$
dividing by $3zy$:
$$y=z$$
so this equation has solutions if and only if $y = z$, and now let's plug our results to the original equation:
$$x^{3}+y^{3} = y^{3}$$
$$x^{3} = 0$$
$$x = 0$$
Therefore :There is no solution when: $$x,y,z\in\mathbb{N}$$
and by mathematical induction we can prove it (instead of the power 3) for all $ n\in\mathbb{N}$

Comment: $x^3+y^3 = z^3 \nRightarrow z-y = x$  for instance $(-1)^3 + 2^3 = (\sqrt[3]{7})^3 = 7$ and $\sqrt[3]{7} - 2 \neq -1$. Later in your post you remark on natural numbers but nonetheless, your original assumption say nothing about what set of numbers $x,y,z$ originate from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$z \equiv y \pmod x$ does not imply $z-y=x$.  We could have $z=y$ or $z-y=2x$ or many other possibilities.

Comment: Also, even before that point in the question, $z^3 \equiv y^3 \pmod{x}$ doesn't necessarily imply $z \equiv y \pmod{x}$. For example, $2^3 \equiv 4^3 \pmod{7}$ but $2 \not\equiv 4 \pmod{7}$.

Comment: yes you're right, this problem is full of mistakes